# On a js form, how to hide/show radio buttons (one or two from a set of 3 buttons) depending on the value of a number entered in a field just above?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the code I am using to display the both the number that will determine the visibility of 2 of the 3 radio buttons:

```html
<td>Nombre de mots:</td>
<td>
  <input id="noMots" name="noMots" type="texte" size="10" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Date de livraison(*):</td>
  <td>
    <input name="dateLiv" type="radio" value="moins48h" />en moins de 48 heures
    <input name="dateLiv" type="radio" value="en5jours" />5 jours ouvrables ou moins
    <input name="dateLiv" type="radio" value="plu5jours" checked />en plus de 5 jours ouvrables
  </td>
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What's the question exactly? How to hide buttons? How to get the value of the field above? Show us the code you tried and so far and we'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the `keyup` event of the input box, then change the style of individual radio boxes depending on the text.

```
document.getElementById("noMots").onkeyup = function () 
{
    var number = parseInt(document.getElementById("noMots"));
   // necessary checks here
    if (number > 8)
    {
         document.getElementById("radio1").style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById("radio2").style.display = 'block';
        // etc.
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along the lines of this:

In the HTML tags of each radio button, you would attach an `onclick="methodName(this.value)"`

And create a method like this:

```
   function methodName(val){
    var rb1 = document.getElementById("id1"); //saving the element in a variable
    var rb2 = document.getElementById("id2");
    var rb3 = document.getElementById("id3");
    if(val == rb1.value){
    rb2.style.visibility = "hidden";
    rb3.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else if (val == rb2.value){
    rb1.style.visibility = "hidden";
    rb3.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else if (val = rb3.value){
    rb1.style.visibility = "hidden";
    rb2.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
 }
```

Let me know if this works out for you.